# Hi, I'm new to python and this project of mine is killing me

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function F(n) that takes n and gives back a list [n, F(n)]. If n does not fulfill the function it returns nothing.
I want to put in an input m so that the code gives back m smallest pairs of [n, F(n)]. I've tried for-loops that calculates and gives back the list in range [a,b] however when I give it an m it gives sometimes more, and sometimes less than the amount required. I've tried pop() and remove()- commands to remove the last elements in the list, however it does not seem to work. I used len(list)

Is there a way to introduce a while loop that automatically searches for solutions for all n from [1.....inf] that stops when number of solutions found equals m? And is there a way to print the list of solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code would be helpful

Comment: A useful title would be helpful as well. Please be so polite and read the [tour], then edit your post (title, remove thanks, full code, expected output, output you get, any errors)

Answer (score -2):

If you're looking for something that has the potential to loop an infinite number of times, use a while loop or recursion.

I don't know python, but the while loop solution would look something like this:

```
int solutions_count = 0;
int n = 0;
const m = 10;
solution = []
while(solutions_count < m) {
  if(fulfills_f(n)) {
    solution += [n, f(n)]
    solutions_count++;
  }
  n++;
}
```

Next time you ask a question, please provide code and add a more suitable title.

Comment: Thanks! appreciate the help

Comment: @sarathequeen no worries. not sure if it's what youre looking for but if you need any help feel free to ask :)